# Rails date difference between now and created_at in days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Hello i have table with ticket where i have valid_from column in DATETIME format and validity column in INTEGER. Now i need find out how many days is ticket active (for how many days it will inactive). Im using integer converting to getting days but it looks that return not days.

```
>> valid_from #DATETIME
=> Thu, 12 Sep 2013 18:24:52 UTC +00:00
>> validity #INTEGER
=> 14
>> DateTime.now
=> Sat, 14 Sep 2013 13:17:32 -0500
>> ((valid_from + validity.days) - DateTime.now.utc).to_i
=> 1037228
```

command `((valid_from + validity.days) - DateTime.now.utc).to_i` returned 1037228 days.. where is a mistake ? thank you

edit:

```
((valid_from + validity.days) - DateTime.now.utc).days
```

returns 1036588.3133747578 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine on my machine, gives

```
valid_from = DateTime.now.utc - 2.days
=> Thu, 12 Sep 2013 18:34:45 +0000 
valid_from
=> Thu, 12 Sep 2013 18:34:45 +0000 
validity
=> 14 
DateTime.now
=> Sat, 14 Sep 2013 11:35:11 -0700 
((valid_from + validity.days) - DateTime.now.utc).to_i
=> 11
```

I don't think there is an error in your formula, etc.  There may be some issue with the time settings on your machine; check to make sure you're using the same time zone everywhere.

**EDIT**

Just realized your `valid_from` is in a different format.  Try replacing it with `valid_from.to_datetime` in your formula.

Comment: oh thank you, in database DATETIMES are UTC and in rails app i didnt change anything :P i dont know even where.. my application.rb and development.rb does not contain timezone setting

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to write something like this:

```
((valid_from + validity.days) - Date.today).to_i
```

Comment: Hello it returns method error
`>> ((valid_from + validity.days)).to_i
=> 1380219892
>> Date.today
=> Sat, 14 Sep 2013
>> ((valid_from + validity.days) - Date.today).to_i
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for Sat, 14 Sep 2013:Date>`